# Is the total wavefunction always the product of the spin and spacetime dependent states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, quantum-spin

Is the total wavefunction always the product of the spin state $ψ_s$ and the spacetime dependent $ψ(x,t)$ state?

I understand conceptually that if we have a homogenous magnetic field, then the evolution of the spin will be independent of $ψ(x,t)$ and so we would multiply the two of them to get the total state. However, I don't understand if this can be mathematically proved or if for any magnetic field, we would again take the product of $ψ_s$ and $ψ(x,t)$.

Comment: No, these are called separable states and not every state can be represented in this form. However, they do span the Hilbert space (ie any state is a linear combination of them). This leads to superpositions and correlations between position and spin that cannot be explained classically (entanglement).  In general, if your Hamiltonian has an interaction between space and spin (eg spin orbit coupling, inhomogeneous magnetic field), a separable state will not stay separable. Thus these superpositions are necessary to describe your state.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

In non-relativistic Quantum mechanics it can be often assumed that orbit angular momentum and spin (internal) angular momentum are separately conserved. In that case one would describe the system with a wavefunction that is a product of a position-dependent part and a spin-dependent part.

However, in relativistic Quantum mechanics in most of the cases only the total angular momentum $J=L+S\,$ is conserved. In that case a decomposition of the 1-particle solutions of the Dirac equation in a pure spacial (position-dependent) and a pure spin part is not always possible.

Actually, if the problem shows any kind of symmetry, then this fact can lead to a separation of variables.
For instance if spherical symmetry is found, one might be able to decompose the 1-particle solution in a radial spin-independent part and a second part dependent on the spherical angles $\theta$, $\phi$ and spin. In case there is no symmetry at all there will be only one function which is also spin-dependent, i.e. a product decomposition is not possible. However, very probably in this case the Dirac-equation cannot be solved analytically, i.e. only a numerical however spin-dependent solution can be found.

Note that I speak of 1-particle solutions instead of a wavefunction. The reason for this is that a wavefunction only has a limited sense in relativistic QM.